# ruby erb template syntax error from a script

Tags: ruby, erb

I have the following my_script.ruby

```
require 'erb'
require 'ostruct'
namespace = OpenStruct.new(:jmx_port => 9200, :markets=> ['CH', 'FR'])
template = File.open("my.json.erb", "rb").read;
puts ERB.new(template).result(namespace.instance_eval { binding })
```

and my.json.erb:

```
{
  "servers" : [ {
    "port" : "<%= jmx_port %>",
    "host" : "localhost",

    "queries" : [
      <% @markets.each do |market| -%>
    {
      "outputWriters" : [ {
        "@class" : "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.StdOutWriter",
      } ],
      "obj" : "solr/market_<%= market %>:type=queryResultCache,id=org.apache.solr.search.LRUCache",
      "attr" : [ "hits","hitratio"]
    },
    <% end -%>
    ],
    "numQueryThreads" : 2
  } ]
}
```

but executing the script by `irb my_script.ruby` I get this error:

```
?> puts ERB.new(template).result(namespace.instance_eval { binding })
SyntaxError: compile error
(erb):10: syntax error, unexpected ';'
;  @markets.each do |market| -; _erbout.concat "\n      "

                           ^
```

for context, my.json.erb file is a puppet file,
and using my_script.ruby I am trying to verify that the file is correct, before sending it to puppet.

what am I doing wrong?

ps: here it is the erb template, used by puppet:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your erb:

- You should use `<% %>` instead of `<% -%>` for things you don't want to output.
- Since you're using an `OpenStruct`, you should use `markets` instead of `@markets`

Here's the final version of the `my.json.erb` file working:

```
{
  "servers" : [ {
    "port" : "<%= jmx_port %>",
    "host" : "localhost",

    "queries" : [
      <% markets.each do |market| %>
    {
      "outputWriters" : [ {
        "@class" : "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.StdOutWriter",
      } ],
      "obj" : "solr/market_<%= market %>:type=queryResultCache,id=org.apache.solr.search.LRUCache",
      "attr" : [ "hits","hitratio"]
    },
    <% end %>
    ],
    "numQueryThreads" : 2
  } ]
}
```

Comment: David is correct. Why we can't use <% -%> i saws that ruby doc http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html  the syntax is available

Comment: @KitHo that's new to ruby 2.0. What version are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3 seems u are correct http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html  it doesn't provider <% -%>  possibly, the puppet has provide <% -%> on its default, and that why the OP has problem if he using 1.9.3 in ruby purely

Comment: thanks, tomorrow I'll upgrade ruby 2.0 and test it again; about writing `markets` instead of `@markets`, can you please elaborate? my goal is to verify a puppet configuration, and this requires to use `@markets`.

Comment: @DavidPortabella An `OpenStruct` is like a wrapper around a ruby hash that gives you friendly accessor methods, which in your case are `markets` and `jmx_port`. There are no instance variables in an `OpenStruct`. In your case, it means that you can only access the markets array by using the `markets` method. There's no instance variable called `@markets`.